# Calculating the equity curve for moving average crossover in Python

Tags: python, pandas, stock, quantitative-finance

I'm trying to calculate a moving average
crossover strategy for 10 ema (10 exponential moving average) and 20 ema
and trying to see how money would grow
if we bought when 10 ema is above 20 ema
and sell when 10 ema is below 20 ema

I am using qqq ticker
as the example here.

The scripts start off with 10k in account,
and when the 10 ema crosses the 20 ema,
we buy as many shares (fractional is okay)
of QQQ, and then we sell those shares when 10 ema is below 20 ema.
I am attempting to not only calculate the buy and sell signals based on the crossoever,
I am also trying to update the account balance.

The way I am calculating account balance is
with equity_curve column in the code below.
When we buy and hold shares,
our equity curve moves with stock_price,
but when we sell we are in cash,
so equity_curve follows cash in hand
unitil we buy again.

The buy and hold equity curve which
buys the first day
and holds forever, is used to compare the returns
with equity_curve column.

I am unsure if my code is calculating what I am trying to do,
despite seeming to run properly.

If you could let me know if the code is correct and even have suggestions to improve it,
I would appreciate it

```
import pandas
import yfinance as yf 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def stackoverflow_example():

    qqq = yf.Ticker('qqq').history('max')
    qqq['10_EMA'] = qqq['Close'].ewm(span=10, adjust=False).mean()
    qqq['20_EMA'] = qqq['Close'].ewm(span=20, adjust=False).mean()
    qqq['10_above_20'] = False
    qqq['10_above_20'] = qqq['10_EMA'] > qqq['20_EMA']

    qqq = qqq.drop(qqq.index[:20])
    qqq['10_above_20'] = qqq['10_above_20'].astype(int)

    #this should calculate when moving average crosses to the top and
    # crosses to the bottom
    qqq['ma_cross'] = qqq['10_above_20'].diff()


    # we then pull out only the areas with 1s and -1 as that's where the action is occuring

    filtered_qqq = qqq.loc[qqq['ma_cross'].isin([1, -1])].reset_index()


     # There should be no consecutive 1s and -1, as you can cross the safe direction twice in a row

    consecutive_rows = filtered_qqq.loc[(qqq['ma_cross'].shift() == 1) & (filtered_qqq['ma_cross'] == 1) |
                           (filtered_qqq['ma_cross'].shift() == -1) & (filtered_qqq['ma_cross'] == -1)]

    if len(consecutive_rows) > 0:
        print("Consecutive occurrences of 1 or -1 found in the following rows:")
        print(consecutive_rows)
    else:
        print("No consecutive occurrences of 1 or -1 found.")



    # Now we look for id for the first signal


    first_one_index = (filtered_qqq['ma_cross'] == 1).idxmax()

    # Set 'Balance' equal to 10000 up to the first_one_index, with Balance being funds
    filtered_qqq.loc[:first_one_index-1, 'Balance'] = 10000
    filtered_qqq['Balance'] = filtered_qqq['Balance'].round(2)

    #Here we buy as many shares as we can fractional shares are okay
    filtered_qqq.loc[first_one_index, 'Shares'] = filtered_qqq.loc[first_one_index-1, 'Balance'] / filtered_qqq.loc[first_one_index, 'Close']
    # set balance to 0 as no more funds
    filtered_qqq.loc[first_one_index, 'Balance'] = 0
    filtered_qqq['Shares'] = filtered_qqq['Shares'].round(2)



    # Now we need to do this for all the ones, and sell for -1s

    for i in range(first_one_index, len(filtered_qqq)):
        if filtered_qqq['ma_cross'].iloc[i] == 1:

            #share should be 0 as we are buying and selling entire lot
            if filtered_qqq['Shares'].iloc[i - 1] == 0:
                
                share_price = filtered_qqq['Close'].iloc[i]
                filtered_qqq.loc[i, 'Shares'] = filtered_qqq['Balance'].iloc[i - 1] / share_price
                filtered_qqq.loc[i, 'Balance'] = 0
        elif filtered_qqq['ma_cross'].iloc[i] == -1:
            if filtered_qqq['Shares'].iloc[i - 1] > 0:
                # sell shares based on Close price
                share_price = filtered_qqq['Close'].iloc[i]
                filtered_qqq.loc[i, 'Balance'] =  filtered_qqq['Shares'].iloc[i-1 ] * share_price
                filtered_qqq.loc[i, 'Shares'] = 0

   
    #Now we want to merge this new info into original dataframe
    filtered_qqq = filtered_qqq[['Date', 'Balance', 'Shares']]
    qqq = qqq.merge(filtered_qqq[['Date', 'Balance', 'Shares']], on='Date', how='left')

    # we need to fix up balance again for original dataframe
    first_one_index = (qqq['ma_cross'] == 1).idxmax()
    qqq.loc[:first_one_index-1, 'Balance'] = 10000

    #forwardfill shares to calculate equity curve
    qqq['Shares'] = qqq['Shares'].ffill()
    qqq['Equity_curve'] = qqq['Balance'].copy()


    #calculate equity curve
    for i in range(0, len(qqq)):
            if  qqq['Shares'].iloc[i] > 0:
                qqq.loc[i, 'Equity_curve'] =  qqq['Close'].iloc[i] * qqq['Shares'].iloc[i]


    qqq['Equity_curve'] = qqq['Equity_curve'].ffill()


    ##buy and hold equity curve, meaning if we just bought and held till today

    qqq['BuyHoldShares'] = 10000/qqq.loc[0, 'Close']
    qqq['BuyHoldEquityCurve'] = qqq['BuyHoldShares'] *  qqq['Close']


    # now we plot both
    plt.plot(qqq['Date'], qqq['Equity_curve'], label='Equity Curve')
    plt.plot(qqq['Date'], qqq['BuyHoldEquityCurve'], label='Buy-Hold Equity Curve')

    plt.xlabel('Date')
    plt.ylabel('Value')
    plt.title('Equity Curve vs Buy-Hold Equity Curve')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()





stackoverflow_example()
```

Comment: I think you should ask your question to [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) forum.